# SQL Server 2008 Pivot without knowing for values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

In SQL server 2008, I have below table.

[image]

I do not how to use Pivot without giving for value in ([val1],[val2],[val2],..)

Any hep in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
create table [VJ1].[dbo].[pivot] (class varchar(25) null, name varchar(25) null)

insert into [VJ1].[dbo].[pivot] (class,name) 
values ('class1','Peter'),
       ('class1','John'),
       ('class1','Marry'),
       ('class1','Ana'),
       ('class1','Julie'),
       ('class1','Lydia'),           
       ('class2','Ryan'),
       ('class2','Aaron'),           
       ('class2','Jacques'),
       ('class2','Jaanu'),           
       ('class3','Nita'),
       ('class3','Nina'),
       ('class3','Lili'),           
       ('class3','Rose'),
       ('class3','Jack'),
       ('class3','Tom')
```

Comment: See my answer here to a very similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554391/sql-query-problem/5554861#5554861

Comment: Note that the insert code is not the same shown in the image. ('class3','Tom') is in the code but not in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to know the values, just the maxium number of names associated with a class.

```
;WITH PvtCte as
(
select  Class,Name,RANK() over (partition by Class order by Name) r
from    [pivot]
)
SELECT class,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
FROM 
(SELECT Class,Name,r
FROM PvtCte) p
PIVOT
(
MIN(Name)
FOR r IN
( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6] )
) AS pvt
```

If you aldo don´t know the maxium number of names associated with a class you can try building the same query above dinamicaly. Hope it helps!