# SQL Query Trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a scenario where I need to convert rows to columns. I likely need to use PIVOT, but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

Here is a simplified version of what I have:
Table: ContentAuthor

```
ContentID | AuthorName
----------------------
1         | Joe
1         | John
1         | Mary
2         | John
2         | Dan
3         | Sam
```

What I would like to get:

```
ContentID | Author1  | Author2  | Author3  | Author4  | Author5
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1         | Joe      | John     | Mary     |          |
2         | John     | Dan      |          |          |
3         | Sam      |          |          |          |
```

At this point I'm not really concerned with the order they show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're absolutely right about needing a PIVOT table.  But to use one you also need to know how many columns you need.  If you can create a dynamic SQL Statement before you make the query then this would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for up to 5 authors per `ContentId` if you need to allow for arbitrary amounts then you will need to use [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554391/sql-query-problem/5554861#5554861)

```
;WITH ContentAuthor(ContentID, AuthorName) AS
(
SELECT 1,'Joe' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'John' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Mary' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'John' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Dan' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Sam'
),T AS
(
 SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContentID ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RN
 FROM ContentAuthor
)
SELECT ContentID,
       [1] AS Author1,
       [2] AS Author2,
       [3] AS Author3,
       [4] AS Author4,
       [5] AS Author5
FROM T
PIVOT(MAX(AuthorName) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS Pvt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY... was the key to what I needed.